# Angular 8: Reactive forms- Currency pipe doesnot transform to reactive form field?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

Why angular pipe does not filter the reactive form value after changing the input value?

Here is the code

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  amount: ['', Validators.required]
});

changeCurr(val) {
  let val1 = val;
  val1 = (!isNaN(val * 1)) ? val1 : 0;
  val1 = this.toFloat(val1);
  this.myForm.patchValue({
    amount: val1
  })
  this.value = this.transform(val1);
}


toFloat(value) {
  // console.log("value", typeof)
  return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
}

onFocus() {
  this.myForm.value.amount = this.myForm.value.amount * 1
}

transform(val) {
  if (val != null || val != '' && val != undefined) {
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      minimumFractionDigits: 2
    })
    let number = this.onlyNumbers(val);
    if (number) {
      return formatter.format(val);
    } else {
      return formatter.format(0);
    }
  }
}

onlyNumbers(value) {
  if (isNaN(value * 1)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input (blur)="changeCurr($event.target.value)" (focus)="onFocus()" [value]="value ? value : '$0.00'" onClick="this.select();" formControlName="amount" placeholder="Amount">
</form>
```

this works initially but when you edit the value, the pipe doesn't reapply onblur.

when i dont change the value and blur function runs, it gives the output 0.00,
I want it should give $0.00, but it returns form value, so how to do that?

when i patch the new values to form, it does not show the value transformed, it just displays the value patched

0.00

I want to tranform the values after updating like currency pipe.

The main issue is that currency pipe does not work when we update the form. So how can i solve the issue?

Comment: This is not a pipe.. an actual pipe would be better. At the moment you’re simply changing the dom value of the input, not the actual formcontrol value..

Comment: Yes i just want to display the filtered value($0.00).. and have the formcontrol value as 0.00 or 0, so how can i do that? Even if the the input value is blank.

Comment: firstly, you should not use [value] together with formControlName. I believe the best way would be to create a MoneyInput component, implementing ControlValueAccessor and add all the logic you need about displaying values there

Comment: @DPro then how to display the filtered value without [value]? Can you pls give some example.